# OpenIdDict logout automatic so fast

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

I use openiddict in netcore 2 project. the problem is after some request user be logout and i cant fix that by increase login time.

Here is my code to add openiddict

```
   services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                    .UseDbContext<DataDbContext>()
                    .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Guid>();
            })
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.UseMvc();

                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/token");

                options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(10));
                options.SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(10));
            })
            .AddValidation();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

after create token

> var ticket =await CreateTicketAsync(request, user);
>   ticket.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)); var tocken =
>   SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties,
>   ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

i used it

> ```
>     private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request, ApplicationUser user)
>     {
>         // Create a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the claims that
>         // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
>         var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
>
>         // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
>         var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
>             new AuthenticationProperties(),
>             OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
>        // ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
>         // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
>         ticket.SetScopes(new[]
>         {
>             OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
>             //OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
>             OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
>             OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
>         }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));
>
>         ticket.SetResources("resource-server");
>
>
>         // Note: by default, claims are NOT automatically included in the access and identity tokens.
>         // To allow OpenIddict to serialize them, you must attach them a destination, that specifies
>         // whether they should be included in access tokens, in identity tokens or in both.
>
>         foreach (var claim in ticket.Principal.Claims)
>         {
>             // Never include the security stamp in the access and identity tokens, as it's a secret value.
>             if (claim.Type == _identityOptions.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType)
>             {
>                 continue;
>             }
>
>             var destinations = new List<string>
>             {
>                 OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken
>             };
>
>             // Only add the iterated claim to the id_token if the corresponding scope was granted to the client application.
>             // The other claims will only be added to the access_token, which is encrypted when using the default format.
>             if ((claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name && ticket.HasScope(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile)) ||
>                 (claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Email && ticket.HasScope(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email)) ||
>                 (claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role && ticket.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Roles)))
>             {
>                 destinations.Add(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
>             }
>
>             claim.SetDestinations(destinations);
>         }
>
>         return ticket;
>     }
> ```

Comment: The problem could be the hosts?